# Not Matching this type name

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, aspect

I have many aspect class in `com.aop.aspect` package. What I want to do is to work all class except for one class named for `com.aop.dao.MyDemoLoggingAspect`

When I run the app, there is an error appeared on the console.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.aop.dao.MyDemoLoggingAspect [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

Here is my aspect class

```
@Aspect
public class LuvAopExpressionsOrder {

    @Pointcut("execution(* com.aop.dao.*.*(..))")
    public void forDaoPackage() {}

    // create pointcut for getter methods
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.aop.dao.*.get*(..))")
    public void getter() {}

    // create pointcut for setter methods
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.aop.dao.*.set*(..))")
    public void setter() {}

    // create pointcut for setter methods
    @Pointcut("!execution(* com.aop.dao.MyDemoLoggingAspect.*(..))")
    public void excludeMyDemoLoggingAspect() {}

    // create pointcut: include package ... exclude getter/setter and MyDemoLoggingAspect
    @Pointcut("forDaoPackage() && !(getter() || setter()) && excludeMyDemoLoggingAspect() ")
    public void forDaoPackageNoGetterSetter() {}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Spring AOP you don't need to be afraid that one aspect will intercept methods from another because Spring does not support that, as is documented in chapter [5.4.2. Declaring an Aspect](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-at-aspectj). Scroll down a bit and look for this info box:

> **Advising aspects with other aspects?**
>
> In Spring AOP, aspects themselves cannot be the targets of advice from other aspects. The `@Aspect` annotation on a class marks it as an aspect and, hence, excludes it from auto-proxying.

So basically your issue is a non-issue.

If however you use [AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj) you are subject to no such limitations and thus have to be careful to exclude other aspects which would normally be intercepted due to matching pointcuts. I recommend to put aspects in packages which are easy to exclude, otherwise you have to do it class name by class name. Use pointcuts like these, depending on your situation:

```java
!within(com.aop.dao.MyDemoLoggingAspect)
!within(com.acme.aop..*)
!within(com.acme..*Aspect)
```